# Specifying parameter in PUT - Rest Web Service

Tags: rest, jersey

I'm building a REST web service using the Jersey API and I've having a problem passing the parameter to the PUT method. The method is this:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("text/html")
public void putHtml (String content) {
    System.out.println("Content"+content);
}
```

I'm calling it using the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function passName()
            {

                xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "/RestWebApp/resources/greeting";
                xmlHttp.open("PUT",url,false);
                xmlHttp.send();
            }
        </script>
        <title>REST Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Put name:<input type="text" name="name"/>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Put" onclick="passName()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PUT method **is** being called since I'm getting "Content " printed in the server console (which is Glassfish) but the parameter is not being read it seems. Is there an @statement or something which I should add to the parameter?

Thanks! 
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the body of the request in your client code.

You need to send some content, e.g.

```
xmlHttp.Send("here is my content")
```

However you have declared your receiving endpoint to accept "text/html".  I would change that to accept "text/plain" instead.  Or if you really want to receive multiple values you could accept "application/x-www-urlencoded-form".  However you will need to format that yourself in the javascript.  Web browsers don't know how to PUT forms.  They can only POST forms.